# ldap3 'unable to open socket' when used in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ldap

I have some code that connects to my companies ldap server as such:

```
s = Server("ldap-server", use_ssl=True,  get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(s, user="uid=login,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx ,dc=xx,dc=xx", password='xxx', auto_bind=True, check_names=True, lazy=False, raise_exceptions=False)
c.open()
c.bind()
```

It returns the expected results when I run the script on its own but it fails with this exception when I run it inside a docker-compose file:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: ('unable to open socket', [(LDAPSocketOpenError('socket ssl wrapping error: [Errno 0] Error',), ('ldap-server', 636))])
```

My docker file is very simple:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    test:
        build: .
        command: python ldp.py
```

and my Dockerfile:

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.6 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test
COPY requirements.txt /test
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /test
```

The kicker is that the same docker-compose file/container works successfully when I run it on other servers, so clearly there is something different about this server but I have no idea what to look for. The same firewall ports are open as on the other successful servers. What can I investigate to solve this?

Comment: Are you exposing that port to the Docker container?

Comment: @JohnGordon, Yes, I tried using  ports: - "636:636" and expose: - "636" and neither had any effect.

Comment: I believe port numbers below 1000 require root access to open.  Is your app running as root?

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes this is running as root and it works successfully on different servers also running as root.

Comment: I came across what I think is this exact problem today. I've found that it works as expected with the 3.7-stretch image, but not 3.7-buster. I've not found a solution yet other than using the older image. It must be something to do with how openssl was compiled/configured, or something with the certificates in those images.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue.  For my case, it's the nginx container.  I had to use_ssl=False, to make it work for container.

One thing though, still haven't figured out why ldap authentication works against our lab ldap server, but not with the prod ldap server, when use_ssl=True and inside the nginx container.  I had to use_ssl=False to make it work in both lab and prod.